# Dealing with the priority of type selectors and class selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list design in sass and compiled as following:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mErCD

```
.thisdiv ul li {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.current {
  background-color: blue;
  list-style: square;
  height: 5em;
}
```

There will be some style changes in .current to be used for jquery later, but it fails to overwrite ".thisdiv ul li".

"!important" and ".thisdiv .current {...}" will do, but according to many articles, they are not so welcomed. Is ".thisdiv .current {...}" a must in this situation?

Comment: `!important` is usually frowned upon, but I see no issue with chaining selectors like `.thisdiv .current {...}`

Comment: What is the HTML markup, and what is the actual CSS code? The CSS code in the question is not valid and won’t work. And what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: It's a sass :( Replace it with compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

**Selector Specificity**

There is an order of importance when determining [**specificity values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in a CSS selector

Change  `.current` to `#current` in markup and css. ID's rank higher than classes -  [**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xer8fema/1/)

---

**From Mozilla Developer Network - Specificity:**

*Least to Greatest*

> - Universal selectors
> - Type selectors
> - Class selectors
> - Attributes selectors
> - Pseudo-classes
> - ID selectors
> - Inline style

*`!important` overrides the above*